# Compare all elements of 2 lists, not necessarily in same order

Tags: list

*Q*:  How to test whether all elements of two lists are the same even though the order may be different?

EXAMPLE:  `(test-fn '(answered cached unread) '(unread answered cached))` => **t**

Comment: Sort and compare or compare pairwise.

Comment: How would you treat duplicates, i.e. are these two lists equal under your `test-fn`? `(1 2 2 3)` and `(1 2 3)`?

Comment: @wvxvw -- The potential duplicates question is a good one -- thank you for bringing that to my attention.  For purposes of this exercise, I should treat `(1 2 2 3)` and `(1 2 3)` as being equal.  The answer by Erik using `cl-set-exclusive-or` looks sufficient, and I'll add a notation to the doc-string about this limitation.

Comment: Added a version catering for duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could [use your list as a set](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Lists-as-Sets.html#Lists-as-Sets)?

- `(cl-set-exclusive-or '(1 2 3) '(3 2 1))` => nil
- `(cl-set-exclusive-or '(1 2 3) '(3 2 1 0))` => (0)

You could put it into a function:

```
(defun order-independent-list-equal (list1 list2)
  "Test if LIST1 and LIST2 hold the same values.
The order of values may be different."
  (not (cl-set-exclusive-or list1 list2)))
```

- `(order-independent-list-equal '(answered cached unread) '(unread answered cached))` => t

There will be a problem if you have multiple instances of the same value though. A more complex version would be something like this:

```
(defun order-independent-list-equal (list1 list2)
  "Test if LIST1 and LIST2 hold the same values.
The order of values may be different."
  (and (equal (length list1) (length list2))
       (not (cl-set-exclusive-or list1 list2))
       (let ((uniques (remove-duplicates list1)))
         (cl-every
          (lambda (x)
            (equal (cl-count x list1)
                   (cl-count x list2)))
          uniques))))
```